# How do I disable screen magnifier at login screen? (Ubuntu 10.10)

Tags: ubuntu, display, accessibility, login-screen, orca

I was trying to get a screen magnifier working for a presentation. I enabled orca but it didn't work well. It magnified way too much and some elements came up really pixelated. So I started using another program (kmag) and everything was fine until I rebooted. Now at the login screen the right half of the screen is magnified (far too much) and is sometimes just black. How do I disable this?

Another thing... I wanted to take a screen shot of the login screen but it doesn't seem to work! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link. It worked for me.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1473233&page=2

Atallcostsky is the one whose post you want to look at. Just do all he said and it works like magic!